# Link on an image not working HTML

Tags: html

I have this logo

```
<img src="images/logo.png" style="margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 10px;width: 80px;" alt="">
```

now to add a link pn this image i use the plain old method

```
<a href="google.com"> <img src="images/logo.png" style="margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 10px;width: 80px;" alt=""> </a>
```

However this doesn't seem to work, Nothing happens on the image and it is not even clickable. Am I missing something? Should I try another way around ?

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: Use google: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_image

Comment: Is the image displayed? When hover over the image, is the mouse icon changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `http://` for all external link.

check below snippet, you can't open `google` in `iframe`, so I changed the URL to `stackoverflow`

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"> <img src="images/logo.png" style="margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 10px;width: 80px;" alt=""> </a>
```

Comment: check above snippet

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="myimage" onclick="document.location=this.id+'.html';return false;"> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="myimage"/> </a>
```